# How to create an sql statement with optional parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

I have a `lessons` table that contains the following fields:

```
id  title   type    language    level
```

The user through the interface can select witch lesson he wants to open.

He will start selecting the language, then the type and finally the level.

During this process I want to query the database using a single sql statement, but of course the first query will have only the language field. I came up with this syntax but it does not work:

```
function queryLessonList (language, type, level){

    const values = [language, type, level];

    const sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE (language=?) AND (? is null OR type=?) AND (? is null OR level=?)";

    return query(sql, values);
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You are on the right track. Can you parameterise the query with named parameters in the framework you are using? If not then something like `type=coalesce(?,type)` will allow you to put the question mark just once.

Comment: Maybe make your value array equal to [language, type, type, level, level] so you are using the same number of parameters you are checking for

Comment: Brody, thanks, that fixed the issue. I didn't realize that the parameter number was not matching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the complexity of checking variables and building out the query, instead you can pass the function an object to match, what you want and the columns you want returning etc (as `*` is not ideal).

**So something like:**

```
function queryLessonList (where = {}, columns = ['*']) {
  let keys = Object.keys(where)
  let values = Object.values(where)
  columns = !columns.length || columns[0] === '*' ?
    '*': columns.map(e => '`'+e+'`').join(',')

  let sql = `
    SELECT ${columns}
    FROM lessons
    ${keys.length ? 'WHERE \`'+keys.join('` = ? AND `')+'\` = ?' : ''}
  `

  return query(sql, values)
}

/*
   SELECT *
   FROM lessons
   WHERE `language` = ? AND `type` = ?
 */
queryLessonList({
  language: 'en',
  type: 'foo'
}, [])


/*
  SELECT `id`
  FROM lessons
*/
queryLessonList({}, ['id'])


/*
  SELECT *
  FROM lessons
*/
queryLessonList()
```